# How to JUnit test an add method for a custom made ArrayList?

Tags: arrays, junit, addition, void

I implemented my custom ArrayList using a resizeable Array, and I would like to unit test my add method to check if the right value getting inserted  to the right position. My add method looks like this:

```
public class MyArrayList<T> implements ArrayListInterface {

private int max=20;
private int index = 0;
private int[] a = new int[max];

@Override
public void add(int value) {
    if(index>max-1) {
        resize();
    }
    a[index] = value;
    index++;


}
```

I am aware, I could just make my method boolean and check what the method returns, but I would like to check that the right value added to the right position. My problem is that my Array is private, and that way it is only possible to reach its value through a getter. Is it a good solution to make a getter for my Array, and compare that to the actual result of the test, or what would be the best solution to test this method?

I have checked couple of other stackoverflow questions in the same topic, but I couldn't find any solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `get()` (`get(position)`, `getLast()`, etc.) method to your class and test using this method. Unit tests should exercise the class through its interfaces, without caring about the internal implementation. Any other class that will interact with your `MyArrayList` will do so through `add()` and `get()`.